# Removing edit menu link

Tags: routes, hooks

How can I remove the "edit" link on this page on the manage menu page (**Structure > Menus > My menu > List links**)?

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) can take care of this by setting `#access` element on menu item operation links.

```
function MYMODULE_form_menu_overview_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach($form as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'mlid:') !== FALSE) {
      $form[$key]['operations']['edit']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```